# how to highlight quickfix result keyword?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Normally, when use vim with cscope, it display the search results in quickfix window at the bottom.
when type :cn in the commandline, it will jump to the beginning of line which contains the keyword.

Is there a solution to highlight the keyword, and position the cursor under the keyword at the same time will be better.

Thanks for your help..

PS: in my opinion, is it possible to jump to the line first, then use a function to search the keyword and highlight it, but how to preserve the keyword info between these actions?

Append: now, the follow function
First: to preserve the keyword gloablly
Second: to display cscope result in the quickfix window.

line 258 always fails. Is there some one knows how to execute the command "cs find s" in Cppsearch function

```
252 "nmap <C-_>s :cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
253 let g:winword = "hello"
254 map ch :call Cppsearch()<cr>
255 function! Cppsearch()
256     let wincursor = line(".")
257     let g:winword=expand("<cword>")
258     normal cs find s g:winword<cr>                                                                                     
259     "call setline(wincursor, "")
260     "call append(wincursor+1, g:winword)
261 endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

`:cnext` will jump to the beginning of the keyword when it knows its start column, i.e. when the quickfix line looks like this:

```
file|3 col 29| cscope
```

When the `col` information is missing, Vim can only locate the line and jumps to the beginning of it.

I don't know enough of *cscope* to help you with why it doesn't include the column.

Comment: well Ingo, the fllowing is my quickfix like: frameworks/av/services/camera/libcameraservice/CameraService.h|144| <<global>> int mNumberOfCameras;                                           and I tried my friends's vim, and all of them jump to the beginning of the line in the main window

Comment: Yeah, right, `144` is the line number; there's no column information attached.